# Why doesn't Standardista Table Sorting and HTML5 Snow effect work on one page?

Tags: javascript

If I put the two javascripts on one html page:

http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/standardista_table_sorting

and

http://www.wilmslowastro.com/html5/snow/snowfall.js

the snowfall works great (very low cpu usage versus other snowfalls), but the Standardista Table Sorting doesn't anymore (until now it showd as a link when people wanted to sort tables, but now there is only the text, not a link).

**Q:** why? what could the problem be?

I tried to check for duplicate variables in the two scripts or something, but didn't found any. At least a hint please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very end of the snowfall script is this:

```
// Prevent the script running on phone devices
if (!(/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|webos|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()))) {
    window.onload = snowFall.init();
}
```

It will clobber any other scripts that try to handle the `onload` event of the `window`.

Have you tried changing the order you attach the scripts to the page? I'm assuming the snowfall script is added last?

Comment: I tried mixing the order in the html file, didn't helped. If I "//" these 3 lines, the sorting works, but the snowfall doesn't. If I only re-add: "window.onload = snowFall.init();" again, the same problem, snowfall works, sorting not. How can I load the snowfall while having the table sort work?

Comment: "document.onload = snowFall.init();" -> this one helped, but not sure it is the best solution, I am not a javascript guy :)

Comment: Try changing it to `window.addEventListener('load', snowFall.init);`

Comment: why is it better? modified it, thanks! both works with this too.

Comment: It's better in this scenario because the `addEventListener` method *adds* to any existing event handlers, whereas using `onload` (or any other `on` event handler) overwrites any previously added handlers. Glad it's working 